# How to see log of nmcli “Network connection failed :unknown reason”

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

My country has network block, so when i use "`nmcli connection up uuid <UUID>`", it always show "Connection establish successful" and then show "Network connection failed :unknown reason:" right now, I find network manager can config log, **my question is** where is network manager log?

Fortunately, when i use Linux mint GUI to enable VPN (Network manager GUI > VPN connections > my vpn) it work well.

**Update**, please don't tell me try to use OpenVPN, my country has blocked this way since too many people use it.

Comment: Network Manager logs to syslog (`/var/log/syslog`).

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/q/885383/157358

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned on comments, you can `grep --color NetworkManager /var/log/syslog | less` or better use [**`journalctl`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/journalctl.1.html):

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

> `-u`, `--unit=UNIT|PATTERN`
> Show messages for the specified systemd unit UNIT (such as a service unit), or for any
> of the units matched by PATTERN. [...]

Hardly your country can block the use of OpenVPN. They probably block IPs, ports, unless they use advanced [Deep Packet Inspection (DPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection) techniques.