# Where are network manager logs? (16.04)

Tags: network-manager, log

I have new Ubuntu and I want to debug some errors in network settings.

I cannot find log for NetworkManager.

`/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/daemon.log` - what people recommend on this stack exchange in other questions - are both empty.

Python script from this page - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingNetworkManager - doesn't exist anymore.

`sudo service network-manager status` displays a *few* lines of the log, but not all.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[**`journalctl`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/journalctl.1.html) does the trick:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

> `-u`, `--unit=UNIT|PATTERN`
> Show messages for the specified systemd unit UNIT (such as a service unit), or for any
> of the units matched by PATTERN. [...]

Comment: This is Systemd only, I suppose.

Comment: Yes. Since the question is on askubuntu, it talks about systemd, because all ubuntu installations are with systemd (except for ancient ones).

Comment: What are You saying exactly? That Ubuntu 14.04 is not Ubuntu? Or users of those "ancient" versions, as You say, are not accepted in this StackExchange network site? You did ask the question without specifying Your Ubuntu version, so...

Comment: I specifically said the version in the title.

Answer (score 15):

You can also try this one. You'll see some Network Manager state changes with this one.

```
sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
```

e.g.,

```
Mar 15 09:06:37 macbookair NetworkManager[1098]: <info>  [xxx] keyfile: add connection in-memory (xxx,"tun0")
Mar 15 09:06:37 macbookair NetworkManager[1098]: <info>  [xxx] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 15 09:06:37 macbookair NetworkManager[1098]: <info>  [xxx] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (xxx)
```

> `-f`, `--follow`
> Show only the most recent journal entries, and continuously print new entries as they
> are appended to the journal.